# Bootstrap 3 datepicker internalization

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, internationalization

I'm using this code for create a booking system:

http://jsfiddle.net/9zjwdypc/

This example working fine, but I can't add the internalization and others option.

I tried this sample code:

```js
$('#dpd1').datepicker({
    language: 'it'
});

$('#dpd1').datepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    weekStart: 1,
    language: "fr",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});

$('#dpd2').datepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    weekStart: 1,
    language: "fr",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});

$(window).load(function(){
  var nowTemp = new Date();
  var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

  var checkin = $('#dpd1').datepicker({
     onRender: function(date) {
       return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
     }
  }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
     if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
     }
     checkin.hide();
     $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
  }).data('datepicker');
  var checkout = $('#dpd2').datepicker({
     onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
     }
  }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
     checkout.hide();
  }).data('datepicker');
});
```

adding:

```js
<script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.js"></script>
```

The same using this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.datepicker.defaults.language = 'it';
});
```

This is the error:
TypeError: $.fn.datepicker.dates is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You have include french language file and then try to use italian language...